# GWT: Crosshairs width

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am using GWT for visualization. For this application, I would like for the cursor to change to a crosshair style when the mouse pointer is in the window of interest.  I accomplish this using :

```
canvas.getElement().getStyle().setCursor(Cursor.CROSSHAIR);
```

This makes the cursor into a cross but I want the cross to span the entire window both vertically and horizontally so the user can see where the cursor is with respect to the axes. How can I accomplish that?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Ranga.

Comment: Found a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7fdh/) that has code that might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch mouse events and draw horizontal line and vertical line. Redraw the canvas on mouse move and mouse out and draw h/v lines on redrawn canvas on mouse move.

```
    final int width = canvas.getOffsetWidth();
    final int height = canvas.getOffsetHeight();
    canvas.addMouseMoveHandler(new MouseMoveHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseMove(MouseMoveEvent event) {
            Context2d context = canvas.getContext2d();

            context.setStrokeStyle("black");

            int x = event.getX();
            int y = event.getY();

            // vertical line
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x - 0.5, 0);
            context.lineTo(x - 0.5, height);
            context.closePath();

            // horizontal line
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, y - 0.5);
            context.lineTo(width, y - 0.5);
            context.closePath();
        }
    });

    canvas.addMouseOutHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
            Context2d context = canvas.getContext2d();

            // clear lines or redraw the canvas

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if there were a way of drawing lines using an XOR filter so you can draw over the previous line and get the underlying graphics back.

Comment: You can use another canvas for drawing image from source canvas and  just draw lines upon it. I can try to write you an example if you write more details about what libraries you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to figure it out. Here's what I am doing : The image I want to draw cross hairs on is generated on a server (it is a spectrogram image). It is placed on a Canvas. I am using the cursor position on the canvas to compute the X and Y coordinates. It works fine but I want to extend the cursor all the way horizontally and vertically so it touches the edges of the window. This way a user will know where they are with respect to the bounds of the axes.